# automate configuration of DistributedMapCacheLookupService service

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to automate the deployment of Nifi with a DistributedMapCacheLookupService.  It doesn't appear to be saved as part of the template and I don't see a way to create it using the REST API.  Is this possible?

Comment: Everything is possible with nifi rest API... Just do what you need from browser and track API calls from devtools.

Comment: uh... that... makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `POST` to the `/controller/controller-services` endpoint, it will create a new Controller Service for the whole controller ("above" the root Process Group even, like where Reporting Tasks are defined), the details are in the [REST API docs](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/index.html) under "Controller"

Comment: daggett's comment was to do it from the UI with a Developers Console up so you can see how the UI makes the same call(s) to create the service, that helps form the body of the request (and the order of REST calls if it takes more than one) so you don't have to figure it out from scratch

Comment: Yeah I did what @daggett suggested and it worked.  somehow I didn't find it in the docs, thanks